# Use Roslyn Workspace Api to get the target framework

Tags: roslyn

Is it possible to get a .NET Visual Studio Project's Target framework using Roslyn's Workspace API.

I could get the Platform, using the CompilationOptions.Platform, but was unable to get the Target framework. If possible, I want to try and use Roslyn to retarget projects.

Comment: Roslyn is for handling code, using the same source the compiler consumes, You can do that using XDoc and the SLN file directly,  Or perhaps through the msbuild api,

Comment: Roslyn doesn't expose this information. It only has information equivalent to what inputs the command line compiler (csc.exe) would need to compile the source. You might be able to figure it out by examining the metadata references for the projects and determine which mscorlib reference is being used.